# Double table view in uiviewcontroller

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

Hi guys i'm new in this group, i want to create an app that have a tableview cotroller as main controlle and when touch the cell open a tableview in a uiview controller that have a button to add item. How can i do to make a correct flow of data?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, several things need to be done.

1.a) In the storyboard, create your **tableView Controller** and your **viewController**. Create also a cocoa touch file for both of your controllers.

1.b) Inside the ViewController, add a object 'tableView' and add an **outlet** for this object. 
Then in the 'ViewDidLoad' method of your ViewController, set `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`. 
Your ViewController has to inherit from **2 protocols** (`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`) This will add two functions, to handle the datas displayed in the tableView of your second ViewController.

1.c) Create a **generic segue** (by control dragging from the tableView Controller to the ViewController) and name it 'YourSegue'

2) In the **tableview controller**, override the function: `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and add the following line: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegue", sender: nil)` which will open the second ViewController.

3) If, additionally, you wanna send datas from the first TableView Controller to your second ViewController, you should override the method 'prepare(for segue:)' which allows you to instantiate variables of your secondviewController.

Hope this helps.